# How to find every item of the list in a string

Tags: python

```
strSpecialChars=['%', 'dBu', 'dB', 'kHz', 'Hz']
str = "-20.0dB"
```

I need to get `True` here as it checks for each item of the list - `strSpecialChars` in the string `str`.

Comment: [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to test each value:

```
>>> strSpecialChars=['%', 'dBu', 'dB', 'kHz', 'Hz']
>>> yourstr = "-20.0dB"
>>> any(s in yourstr for s in strSpecialChars)
True
```

where I renamed `str` to  `yourstr` to avoid masking the built-in type.

`any()` will only advance the generator expression passed to it until a `True` value is returned; this means only the first 3 options are tested for your example.

You could use `str.endswith()` here:

```
any(yourstr.endswith(s) for s in strSpecialChars)
```

to limit matches to only those that *end* with any of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda s: s in "-20.0dB", strSpecialChars)
```

You may need to convert the output through `list` to actually see it.